# How to find larges file in a directory tree, in php?

Tags: php, move

I have a folder, that contains other folders, which may or may not contain other folders, where the files might reside. I want to scan the entire dir structure, and find files larger than 100MB, and move these files to the top level directory.

Whats a good way to accomplish this, in php?

For example:

```
/data/1/subfolder/id33/big_file.avi
/data/4/another_big_file.avi
/data/56/something/big_file2.avi
```

I need to move these 3 files, into `/data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        return $this->getSize() > 100*1024*1024;
    }
}

$it = new MyFilterIterator(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/data")));

foreach($it as $file) {
    //move ...
}
```

Comment: In place of `filesize(parent::current())`, how about using `$this->getSize()` or with less *magic*, `$this->current()->getSize()` or, finally, if you really must `parent::current()->getSize()`?

Comment: As soon as I try to exclude the smaller files, it stops reading the lower directories 9even though they have sufficiently large files)

Comment: @sal wow `$this->getSize()` is very sick. I got curious how it worked the magic is in the `get_method` handler of the "dual iterators" (iterators that encapsulate other iterators): http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/spl/spl_iterators.c?revision=298633&view=markup#l1161

Answer (score 2):

Simply scan all subfolders with

```
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/data");
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
    //work with file (which is simplya a path here actually) here
}
```

you'll add some condition there, such as

```
if (filesize($file) > 100e6) {
    rename($file, '/data/filename...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [DirectoryIterator](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL-DirectoryIterator.html) from SPL to browse a directory and even recurse into it if you need. To take the next step, you can use a Filter to filter the results by filesize and then do what you need.

Here's a rough example: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL-DirectoryIterator.html#17